# Email said to be null is not with Rails 3.2 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Rails 3.2 and Devise, I have overridden the Registrations Controller with a custom one. I did not change the code in the `create` method at all, it is the original one in Devise.

But strangely enough, I keep getting this error whenever I'm trying to create/sign up a new User.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "payroll", "sign_in_count", "updated_at", "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"
```

But below it, everything seems to be ok as the User is getting a valid email.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"8/ZKW11lF22WYKV2K36zBkSk6DSU36/1/zU54a2IRmM=",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"someguy",
 "email"=>"email@yahoo.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up",
 "format"=>"user"}
```

I am not quite sure what other code to paste in here as everything is obviously right for me. So please ask for anything which might help.

This is my **Registrations controller**, but `create` basically has the same code its `super`. The error occurs at the line which has `resource.save`.

```
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save

      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

Apparently, all of the fields are `nil`. This is the query that it executes:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "payroll", "sign_in_count", "updated_at", "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 17 Apr 2013 19:34:22 BST +01:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", nil], ["first_name", nil], ["last_name", nil], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["payroll", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["updated_at", Wed, 17 Apr 2013 19:34:22 BST +01:00], ["username", ""]]
```

Comment: Please post your `registrations_controller.rb`

Comment: @benchwarmer, I've attached it to the original post.

Comment: Can you add the `build_resource` method? I'm assuming it is in your super class `RegistrationsController`?

Comment: `build_resource` is not defined by me, it is from Devise, I believe. Anyway, it does it's job and it does create a valid User. If I say something like `abort(resource.email)` it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is email a mass-assignable on the User class? Try declaring attr_accessible :email in the User class.

Comment: Yes, it is. It seems that all the fields are passed as nil to Rails when it tries to insert it into the DB.